# WP8 AudioPlaybackAgent bug?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a problem with playing audio tracks with the `AudioPlaybackAgent` on devices running WP8. It works perfectly on WP7, but not on WP8. It only works sometimes for WP8, so there is no clear steps on how to reproduce it either. What seems to be the problem is that when a new track is about to play and I have set the `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track` to the new `AudioTrack`, it don't receive `onPlaystateChanged.TrackReady`.

Why is this? I don't receive `onError` either.

Is there a known bug with playing audio on WP8 devices? It happens about 50% of the time, and the same track can both work and not work. What can be the problem here? Please help. Any from Microsoft that can help on this? That would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fact this occurs 50% of the time makes me suspect this could be a race condition which didn't occur on WP7.

Are you doing any thread-locking (using `Mutex`, `lock()` etc) from your background agent when changing tracks? I had something similar for a WP8 background audio app that was previously working on WP7 and traced it back to a deadlock in my code.

Don't forget that WP8 now has dual-core processors and is more likely to hit such issues. See [this post from someone on the Windows Phone team about back-compat between WP8 and 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2012/11/08/windows-phone-8-evolution-of-the-runtime-and-application-compatibility.aspx). Especially interesting is the section named "Runtime behavior changes" in that post.

Comment: I also just thought of that, and I will test to see if there are any deadlocks or race conditions, and update my findings. Any other ideas in the meantime? Known issues?

Comment: It's working now I've removed the deadlock :). I found it using the debugger: when the deadlock hit I paused the app and I could see which threads were waiting for what lock object in the Threads view.

Comment: May I ask what your deadlock was? And how can you see what lock object it is waiting for in the Threads window?

Comment: In particular use of a Mutex to protect access to an file in IsolatedStorage. You can tell by looking at the Location column : for a lock() it will be `mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Monitor.Enter`. For a Mutex it will be something similar. If you hover with your mouse over this Location it should give you the full call stack of where the thread is waiting.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but of course it does not refer to my code. The Location column is giving me mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Threading.Thread.Sleep and at the bottom [Native to Managed Transition]. Also, all calls to IsolatedStorage finishes their lock() Simple check to just print a line before and after the lock.. I think you're getting me in the right direction, just need a little more!